# How can I share a template between two components using Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have two components: `SpecialButtonComponent` and `SpecialButtonDerivativeComponent`.

The `SpecialButton` component automatically uses the template found at `/app/templates/components/special-button.hbs`.

I would like for `SpecialButtonDerivativeComponent` to use the same template, but so far I'm having no luck trying to go with this technique:

```
// app/components/special-button-derivative.js
import SpecialButtonComponent from './special-button';

export default SpecialButtonComponent.extend({
  templateName: 'components/special-button'
});
```

I've also tried using `layoutName` instead of `templateName`, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Components do not have a `templateName`.

I would try to set `layout` to null and then specify a `layoutName`.

Comment: `layoutName` will do it.

Comment: in ember 2.0 that property is not needed, but you have to make sure for the extended component does not have a template file created. Because if there is a template file for it, that will override the inherited template. So make sure to remove it's template :)

Comment: @FarzanMajdani As of v2.12 your suggestion doesn't actually seem to work as described, unless the parent component happens to have explicitly set it's `layout` property. 

To make this work in the general case, you need to set the subclass' `layout` to the parent's template. See this GH issue for details: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15156

Answer (score 0):

In `Ember 2.2` `layoutName` became a private API. I would recommend `Gabriel Grant` solution and set the `layout` property of the parent component.

```
// parent-component
import Component from '@ember/component';
import layout from '../templates/parent-component';

export default Component.extend({
  layout
});


// child-component
import ParentComponent from './parent-component';

export default ParentComponent.extend({
});
```