# Extend Ember component without changing template

Tags: ember.js, web-component

I have an Ember application and want to extend a component to override some functionality, but don't want to change or duplicate the template.

However, if I just import and extend the component, nothing is rendered.

How can I make my extended component render using the template that I extended from?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to the question answered here [How can I share a template between two components using Ember CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27450643/94235) I was able to add a `layoutName` to the child component pointing to the parent template and solved my problem.
My code finally looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ExtendFromComponent from './extend-from';

export default ExtendFromComponent.extend({
  layoutName: 'components/extend-from'
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You must have done something wrong. In Ember 2.0.0 you can create a component which extends from another component(and shares its template) using following ES6 syntax in `components/second-component`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ExtendFromComponent from './extend-from';

export default ExtendFromComponent.extend({
  // ...
});
```

It renders fine with template and properties of first component. If you still can't get it right then please add your code to question.

Comment: How do I check what is my ember version number?

Comment: Check in bower.json. You should have: "ember" : "version".

Comment: it's 1.12.0. is that possible in this version? or should rewrite the template?

Comment: To use the `extend-from` component's template, be sure that you don't have a template for your new component as this will override. Remove `templates/components/second-component.hbs`

Comment: As of v2.12 this doesn't actually seem to work as described, unless the parent component happens to have explicitly set it's `layout` property. 

To make this work in the general case, you need to set the subclass' `layout` to the parent's template. See this GH issue for details: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/15156